# how to clear the item on notification bar by using phonegap localnotification plugin

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, localnotification

As the title, I'm using android localnotification phonegap plugin. Now I can force a notification on that bar, and if I touch on that one, the app will be re-open, but that notification is still on the notification bar.

So the question here is how to clear that notification on the notification bar once the app was re-opened?

Thanks.

Comment: still waiting for the answers...

Answer (score 0):

In `AlarmReceiver.java` look at `AlarmReceiver::onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)`. You have to set `AutoCancel` for the `Notification`.

Depending on the API version you are using this may look different. For the version 17 it could look like this:

```
final Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setTicker(tickerText)
    .setSmallIcon( context.getResources().getIdentifier("myicon" , 
                                "drawable", context.getPackageName()) )
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
    .setContentText(notificationSubText)
    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
//    .setVibrate(new long[] { 0, 100, 200, 300 })
    .setAutoCancel(true) // <------- here you remove the message 
    .build();

notificationMgr.notify(notificationId, notification);
```